# Can a Fermi gas and a Bose gas be both at the same pressure and temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions, bosons

The title says it all: can a Fermi gas and a Bose gas be both at the same pressure and temperature?

It comes from a quiz about statistical mechanics

Comment: What happens to each type of gas in the high temperature, low density limit?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Both the distributions reduce to Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution in the classical limit = extremely low concentration or extremely high temperature or both.

Comment: I would say at low temperatures, when the ground state is crowded, there are big differences between both types of gases, and at high temperatures they must be more or less the same as pauli's principle becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @gerardpc Exactly! There you have your answer right?